# Is the ID of issues, milestone and pull request unique in Github API?

Tags: github-api

i've seen there is an id for Milestone, Pull Request, Issues and Comments in Github API,
is the id given unique globally?
For example this issue here : https://api.github.com/repos/lerman25/Omertestforapi/issues/1
hast the ID '672029502' , is this the only issue with such ID?
thanks.